# Variable does not exist: Trigger

Tags: apex

I am trying to get all the Account's IDs owned by a particular user.But I am getting error.

```
trigger UserGoingLeave on User (before update) {
User userOnLeave = Trigger.new();
Id delegatedApprover = userOnLeave.DelegaterApproverId;
List<id> accId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId = :userOnLeave.Id];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call Trigger.new this returns a list of objects (It doesn't matter if you updated only one record) that have been involved in the DML operation. I think that of the premises of salesforce is that you have to bulkify every trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Not Trigger.new() but Trigger.new. But you need all Ids and I suggest to use the following approach

```
trigger UserGoingLeave on User (before update) {
  Set<ID> acctId 
     = new Map<ID, Account>([select ID from Account where OwnerID in :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ])
        .keySet();
```

}

And that's it.
If you need an array just create List from the set